# AngularJS service only running the first time controller is used

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following controller that uses a service Customers to return customers. The problem is that its only executing the service the first time the controller is run. Looking at my server I see its only performing the get request the FIRST time the controller used(loading that view) if I change views and say add a customer and come back to the view that list customers its not updated because there was not another get request from the service.

```
  .controller('searchCTRL', ['$scope', '$http', 'Customers', function($scope, $http, Customers) {
        $scope.customers = Customers;
        $scope.deleteCustomer = function(id) {
            $http.delete('/api/customer/' + id)
                .success(function(data) {
                    $scope.customers.data = data;
                })
                .error(function(data) {
                    console.log('Error: ' + data);
                });
        };
  }])
```

and

```
.factory('Customers', function($http){
    var Customers = {};
    $http.get('/api/customer')
        .success(function(data) {
            Customers.data = data;
        })
        .error(function(data){
            console.log('error: ' + data);
        });
    return Customers;
});
```

if I stay on the view and reload the page it gets the data like it should but any subsequent visits to the page no longer execute the get. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Angular .factory is a singleton so it will always only run once.  Also, the `$http` call is async so you should be using `promise` in order to get the data to your controller.  Try the following:

```
.factory('Customers', function($http, $q){
    return function () {
        var d = $q.defer();
        $http.get('/api/customer')
            .success(function(data) {
                d.resolve(data);
            })
            .error(function(data){
                console.log('error: ' + data);
                d.reject(data);
            });
        return d.promise;
    };
});
```

and in your controller:

```
.controller('searchCTRL', ['$scope', '$http', 'Customers', function($scope, $http, Customers) {
    Customers().then(function (data) {
        $scope.customers = data;
    });
...
```

As `$http` returns a promise, you can further simply your `.factory` by doing:

```
.factory('Customers', function($http){
    return function () {
        return $http.get('/api/customer');
    };
})
```

For more detail, see [documentation for $http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http).

Comment: The function could be shortened to simply `return $http.get('/api/customer');`. Also, the question seems to want to simulate "promise unwrapping", i.e. immediately returning an object which later is filled with data. (Another option would be to go for your promise returning example, and then resolve it in the `$route` configuration.)

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved the problem. I'll have to read up on the promises, I haven't used them yet. Seems reasonable to return a promise of data until the data is available. Thanks again!